# Disabling parallel execution for scct:test in SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt, code-coverage, scct

I've been working on a Scala application. To do it properly, I want the kernel of my code to be completely covered by tests. To do that, I'm using [the SCCT plugin for SBT](http://mtkopone.github.io/scct/).

Unfortunately, my tests rely on an in-memory database (h2). Therefore, my tests cannot run in parallel. However, sbt runs all tasks in parallel by default.

To solve this, I've modified `build.sbt` file to disable parallel execution of the tests as:

```
parallelExecution in Test := false
```

The problem with the build configuration is that to generate code coverage, I need to run `sbt scct:test` rather than `sbt test`.

I've tried to disable the parallel execution of `scct:test` but the code below does not compile:

```
parallelExecution in scct:test := false
```

Can anyone help me by either disabling the parallel execution in `scct:test` by either setting the flag, or by making `scct:test` run in the test context?

Comment: scoverage:test disables parallel execution and isn't line coverage like scct https://github.com/scoverage/scalac-scoverage-plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the task name is actually `ScctTest`.  Try:

```
parallelExecution in Test := false
parallelExecution in ScctTest := false
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating a new database for each test and making the db name that is created be a random name for each one so they dont clash.  Works well as long as you dont have absolutely massive numbers of tests which require a database.

Comment: You are correct I've only got four test classes which require a database. I've always wanted to separate them. However I'm trying to learn a new ORM which can be a bit tricky.  Until recently, I thought that it only allowed a single database session. I'm already inventorying the changes that need to be made.